# Add badge (supplementary view) to UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewlayout

Is there any way to add a badge `NSCollectionLayoutSupplementaryItem`) to a `UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration`?

I'm trying to implement a sidebar using [Modern Collection Views](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/collection_views/implementing_modern_collection_views):

```
var configuration = UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration(appearance: .sidebar)
...

let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection.list(using: configuration, layoutEnvironment: layoutEnvironment)
```

but I can't find how to implement the `badge` configuration:

```swift
let badgeAnchor = NSCollectionLayoutAnchor(edges: [.top, .trailing], fractionalOffset: CGPoint(x: 0.3, y: -0.3))
let badgeSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .absolute(20),
                                                  heightDimension: .absolute(20))
let badge = NSCollectionLayoutSupplementaryItem(
                layoutSize: badgeSize,
                elementKind: "badge",
                containerAnchor: badgeAnchor)
```

like the example code Apple provides:

```swift
let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize, supplementaryItems: [badge])
```

(the example code that Apple provides, crashes btw)

Any ideas on how to implement the badge to `UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration` or is not possible?

Comment: hey there, I was digging through that collection view couple of days ago, and also got the crash for "Item Badges". Spent some time now to fix it, I will post it as an answer if you don't mind :]

Comment: What I do is simply add it as a subview to the cell and position it manually. A cell is just a view so you can put whatever you want there. The only caveat is that a list cell clips to the bottom bounds.

Answer (score 3):

In the sample project, element kind for `badge` was wrong. It was

```
let badge = NSCollectionLayoutSupplementaryItem(
            layoutSize: badgeSize,
            elementKind: ItemBadgeSupplementaryViewController.badgeElementKind,
            containerAnchor: badgeAnchor)
```

and the error message actually made sense:

```
"the view returned from -collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath: does not match the element kind it is being used for. When asked for a view of element kind 'badge-element-kind' the data source dequeued a view registered for the element kind 'badge-reuse-identifier'."
```

Just change `elementKind` of the badge (in `ItemBadgeSupplementaryViewController`) to

```
elementKind: BadgeSupplementaryView.reuseIdentifier
```

And to answer your question, the badge will be a supplementary item of your `NSCollectionLayoutItem`.

Comment: How can I register the `supplementary item` using `UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration`? (btw thank you for the solution of the apple's project)

Comment: @pableiros now I am a little confused. Why you wanna do it with ```UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration```? And I am not sure that ```UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration``` can change your badge style collection view, maybe? I am a little confused, can you elaborate a little?

Comment: I have a [Sidebar menu like the photos app](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/bars/sidebars/) on an iPad app and I want to add a badge item to indicate you have a new notification on an item. So I want to know if it is possible to add a badge using `UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration` because with that type is the only way to implement the Sidebar menu style natively without custom styles.

Answer (score 1):

There's an API for this since iOS14 https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicellaccessory/3600872-label

```
cell.accessories = [.label(text: String(item.count ?? 0))]
```

In the cell registration add an accessory of type label to the cell.accessories array property.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using supplementary views, I found adding a basic badge accessory view is somewhat simpler.

```
let cellRegistration = UICollectionView.CellRegistration<UICollectionViewListCell, ContentItem> {[weak self] (cell, indexPath, contentItem) in

    // Set item data in cell
    var config = cell.defaultContentConfiguration()
    config.image = contentItem.image
    config.text = contentItem.name
    cell.contentConfiguration = config

    // Add an unread count badge if there are unread items.
    if contentItem.unreadCount != 0 {
        let badgeLabel = UILabel()
        badgeLabel.backgroundColor = .red
        badgeLabel.textColor = .white
        badgeLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        badgeLabel.clipsToBounds = true
        badgeLabel.text = "  \(contentItem.unreadCount)  "
        let viewConfig = UICellAccessory.CustomViewConfiguration(customView: badgeLabel, placement: .trailing(displayed: .always))
        let badgeAccessory = UICellAccessory.customView(configuration: viewConfig)
        cell.accessories = [badgeAccessory]
    }
}
```